# How to make a query for mongodb using spring to return objects ignoring accent?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, nosql

I am using Query from mongodb and i am trying to do a search with the attributes "name", "code" and "department". However, I want to ignore upper/lower case, accents and be able to search for only part of the string.

obs: Without the `$collation {...}` operator, the method works. But with this operator the method does not work.

Whats wrong?

> ```
> @Query("{ $or: [ { 'name': { $regex: ?0, $options: 'i', $collation: { 'locale': 'pt', 'strength': 2 } } }, { 'department': { $regex: ?0, $options: 'i', $collation: { 'locale': 'pt', 'strength': 2 } } }, { 'code': { $regex: ?0, $options: 'i', $collation: { 'locale': 'pt', 'strength': 2 } }}]}")
> Page<SubjectModel> findAllByNameAndDepartmentAndCode(Pageable pageable, String name, String department, String code);
> ```

}